# How can I chat without microphone?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, chat, microphone

HOw can I do this on my laptop? I've an `Acer Extensa 4620`. I want to know the settings for both Windows XP and Windows 7.

Comment: Was he voice-chatting or using some text-to-speech program. Maybe his laptop comes with a built-in microphone so he didn't have to connect one?

Comment: Why is downvote?

Comment: avirk, I'm not the downvoter, but I'm guessing that it was downvoted because your question is incomprehensible. Or possibly silly, if I'm understanding it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That model computer on Acer's website says that it has a webcam, which means it will also have a microphone that you can configure in Skype or whatever other program you want.

Windows 7
Control Panel
Hardware and Sound
Manage Audio Devices
Recording Tab
Set the Microphone device to whatever is tied to your webcam, to your default communication device.
Configure your chat program to use this microphone.

Windows XP should be very similar...

Comment: Hmmmm nice I'll take a look on that.

Comment: My wife's Sony Vaio has a Webcam but no built-in microphone so you can have one without the other (even though it seems kinda stupid) - but the specs for the 4620 DO say it has a mic.